# Getting driving direction and distance through my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

There is an application in iPhone called `Map`. we could give some destination and get the `driving direction`, `distance` and the `time` to that location from it. I need to know how this works ?

Is there any native `iPhone frameworks` that i could use to get this ? or is it from a `Google` API that i should use ?

[and here's an image of the application](http://img-ipad.lisisoft.com/img/1/6/1669-3-mapd-map-distance.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, use the mapkit and corelocation frameworks. also check [this](http://www.andreanolanusse.com/en/using-ios-mapkit-and-corelocation-with-delphi-prism-and-monotouch/) out